# Show API fetched data to ckeditor dialogue box

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am trying to show API fetched data to ckeditor dialogue box. My code is like below.

```
CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
{
    var dialogName = ev.data.name;
    var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

    if ( dialogName == 'image' )
    {
      dialogDefinition.dialog.resize( 700, 500 );
      var API_KEY = 'adfasdf';
      var URL = "https://pixabay.com/api/?key="+API_KEY+"&q="+encodeURIComponent('red roses');
      var images; 
      
      $.getJSON(URL, function(data){
      if (parseInt(data.totalHits) > 0)          
        $.each(data.hits, function(i, hit){ images = "<img class='img' src='"+hit.pageURL+"'>"; });
      else
        console.log('No hits');
      });

      dialogDefinition.addContents({
          id : 'uploadTab',
          label : 'Upload',
          elements : [
            {
              type: 'text',
              id: 'uploadField',
              label: 'Upload',     
            },
            {
              type: 'html',
              id: 'foo',
              html: images,
            }
          ]
      })
    }
});
```

But images are not showing in dialogue box of ckeditor.